# Terminal SSH command not working while connecting to another computer

Tags: ssh, terminal, osx-yosemite

After entering the command:

```
ssh [username]@[ip address of remote computer]
```

I got the error:

```
ssh: connect to host 10.3.32.1 port 22: Connection refused
```

Does anyone know what causes this?

Comment: Usually this means that there is no service listening on that port on the remote machine, _or_ that there is some firewall blocking that port.

Comment: If you're certain that the other computer has the ssh service up and running (ie on that computer you can do `ssh localhost`), and you can ping that computer, then it can be a routing or firewall problem.

Comment: Thanks... I'll re-start my router, and check my firewalls

Comment: Is your target across WAN or LAN?